# Missing ASP.NET Web Application in visual studo 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Im trying to follow along with code school curriculum but i am unable to find any template for ASP.NET Web Application with my version of visual studio community 2015. My new project dialog looks like this[visual studio query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcE47.png)

but i seem to be missing the whole web selection option. I am currently running windows 8 and this is the about/help for my version of VS:

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01055

Installed Version: Community

Visual Basic 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA718
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA718
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Visual C++ 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA718
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   4.2.60128.3
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your VS 2015 installation miss the [Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935).